# Where are WMX connection files (JTC) stored?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-workflow-manager

I know that JTC files are SDE connection files with the extension changed from 'sde' to 'jtc'. They are not stored in the folder with the normal sde connection files. Where do they get stored?

Comment: Mind writing a tag summary for the `wmx` and `jtx` tags? Also I think since WMX replaces JTX that `jtx` should be a synonym of `wmx`.

Comment: I added summaries (need to be approved), but there aren't enough JTX tags to suggest a synonym.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are usually stored in: %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\ESRI\WMX\Database

XP: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\ESRI\WMX\Database
Win7: C:\ProgramData\ESRI\WMX\Database

However that location can be modified by the WMXAdvancedSettings.exe, located in %ProgramFiles%\WMX\Bin (C:\Program Files\WMX\Bin\WMXAdvancedSettings.exe). This application changed the  ConnPath value under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ESRI\JTX

[image]